# c# lazy load of items in listView when search for items inside of listView

Tags: c#, listview

I am trying to make search inside of a listView. I tried it in 2 ways, first is to search from listView and second way to search from database then populate list with founded items. I can see that both ways have pretty long time to load with only 30 records. I saw in many tutorials that this work fast and without any load even with many records in database or listView. I found that in 2nd example when i search inside of listView itself this presents a issue `LoadAll();` because after each typed letter or number, it populate list again and slow down application. Is there any way to make this to work without long time to load or any simplest way to do it ?

1st example with searching inside of database

```
    private void usersSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (usersSearch.Text != "")
        {
            searchUsers(usersSearch.Text.ToLower());
        }
    }

    private void searchUsers(string searchTerm)
    {
        usersList.Items.Clear();

        string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnection"].ConnectionString;
        dbConn = new MySqlConnection(conn);

        string query = "SELECT id, email, username, password FROM " +
            "users WHERE id LIKE '%" + searchTerm + "%' OR email LIKE '%" + searchTerm + "%' OR username LIKE '%" + searchTerm + "%'";

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, dbConn);

        dbConn.Open();

        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new string[] { reader["id"].ToString(), reader["email"].ToString(), reader["username"].ToString(), reader["password"].ToString()});

            usersList.Items.Add(item);
        }

        reader.Close();
        dbConn.Close();
    }
```

2nd example to search inside of a listView items

```
    private void usersSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadAll(); // loads all data in list

        if (usersSearch.Text != "")
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem item in usersList.Items)
            {
                bool founded = false;

                string value0 = item.SubItems[0].Text;
                string value1 = item.SubItems[1].Text;
                string value2 = item.SubItems[2].Text;

                if (value0.ToLower().Contains(usersSearch.Text.ToLower()))
                {
                    item.Selected = true;
                    founded = true;
                }
                else if (value1.ToLower().Contains(usersSearch.Text.ToLower()))
                {
                    item.Selected = true;
                    founded = true;
                }
                else if (value2.ToLower().Contains(usersSearch.Text.ToLower()))
                {
                    item.Selected = true;
                    founded = true;
                }

                if (!founded) usersList.Items.Remove(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There will always be performance cost if you go to database for every character the user types.

Comment: Can not you get the values one time only and save it in the array/ list  variable. Then find it from the local list instead of calling the DB every time?

Comment: Are you using DisplayMember and ValueMember properties?

Comment: If you really want to change the result list on every character, use the second approach but load all the records first **once**, not all the time. And then *keep* that list (don't remove stuff from it). Use a *second* list for displaying. And to get that second list, don't use `ToLower` all the time. Or at all. Try something like `var secondList = new List<ListViewItem>(); foreach(var item in usersList.Items) { for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) { if (item.SubItems[i].Text.IndexOf(usersSearch.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0) { secondList.Add(item); break; } } }`.

Answer (score 1):

It will be painfully slow if - for every character you type in the TextBox - you are going to make a Database query to fetch the matching "Suggestions". To Design this effectively you have to make several decisions (based on what the usage would be like).

1. Rather than per character - Go to Database only when user input has a "Minimum" length. Say 3 characters or so.
2. If your Database/RecordSet from where you need to do "auto complete" is not Humungous and not ever growing - Can you Cache them during Application Load/Startup.
3. If recordset is ever growing and you need it to be realistic/real time. Can you not Virtualize? i.e. fetch only top 5 or 10 Suggestions rather than all.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest loading all data in the list view first ( on loading the page). 
When user search in the list view, it should just select the match from the existing data( which is already available with the list view)

Comment: I need to update listView only with results that match string in search box and show only them, not select founded.